# KDE doesn't start on Ubuntu Server on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: server, kubuntu, kde, raspberrypi

I'm trying to install KDE interface on Ubuntu server for Raspberry Pi 4.

I've followed the instructions on [How to install Ubuntu on your Raspberry Pi | Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#1-overview)

So, basically, I've upgraded the OS with

```
apt update
apt full-upgrade
```

Then I've installed Kubuntu by using the following command:

```
apt install kubuntu-desktop
```

But nothing happens, the KDE interface don't start. Even the KDM daemon don't start, I suppose.

After installing the `kubuntu-desktop` package, what do I need to do?

Comment: What happens when you use the command `startx`?

Comment: Have you restarted the system/RPi?

Answer (score 0):

From everything I can find, sddm does not work on Raspberry Pi.

Go to tty2 by hitting Ctrl-Alt-F2, log in from the CLI there then you can try to install lightdm with

```
sudo apt install lightdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
sudo reboot
```

Hopefully that works for you.